# How to use gnomevfs.get_mime_type()?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Python gnome binding have `gnomevfs` module that theoretically can get MIME types. But calling `gnomevfs.get_mime_type()` with any name other than "/dev/null" raises error "RuntimeError: there was an error reading the file". For example:

```
import gnomevfs
gnomevfs.get_mime_type( "/tmp/a.py" )
gnomevfs.get_mime_type( "file://tmp/a.py" )
gnomevfs.get_mime_type( "file:///tmp/a.py" )
gnomevfs.get_mime_type( "file://./tmp/a.py" )
```

This all fails. With any file / folder name except "/dev/null" :(. `/tmp/a.py` exists and acessible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me.  Have you tried with other files in other directories?  Are you sure that the user under which Python is being run has access to /tmp/a.py?